# Calculate Percentage Based on each unique column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the long post. I have a table with following columns
CandidateName, Constituency, Party, Result

```
CREATE TABLE `parlia`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CANDIDATE_NAME` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT '',
  `REGION` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CONSTITUENCY` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PARTY` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT '',
  `RESULT` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 295 CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

```
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (31, 'OPPONG SAMUEL', 'ASHANTI', 'AKROFUOM', 'NDC', 7484);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (32, 'KWABENA APPIAH-AKROFUOM', 'ASHANTI', 'AKROFUOM', 'NPP', 10249);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (34, 'NATHONY KWAKYE-AMEYAW', 'ASHANTI', 'AKROFUOM', 'PPP', 129);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (49, 'HON ALHAJI MOHAMMED MUNTAKA MUBARAK', 'ASHANTI', 'ASAWASE', 'NDC', 43917);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (50, 'NANA OKKERE TAWIAH ANTWI', 'ASHANTI', 'ASAWASE', 'NPP', 31013);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (51, 'JERRY JOSEPH QUAYSON', 'ASHANTI', 'ASAWASE', 'PPP', 458);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (90, 'DACOSTA KOFI YEBOAH', 'ASHANTI', 'BEKWAI', 'NDP', 92);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (91, 'AKWASI GYAMFI', 'ASHANTI', 'BEKWAI', 'INDP', 656);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (92, 'DR.JOE OTENG ADJEI', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOMTWE', 'NDC', 17235);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (93, 'HON. SIMON OSEI MENSAH', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOMTWE', 'NPP', 34790);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (95, 'YAW WIREDU', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOMTWE', 'PNC', 58);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (96, 'HON KWAME ADARKWAH', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOME FREHO', 'NDC', 5467);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (97, 'KWADWO KYEI FRIMPONG', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOME FREHO', 'NPP', 14293);
INSERT INTO `parlia`(`id`, `CANDIDATE_NAME`, `REGION`, `CONSTITUENCY`, `PARTY`, `RESULT`) VALUES (98, 'OWUSU AUGUSTINE', 'ASHANTI', 'BOSOME FREHO', 'CPP', 143);
```

I'd like to calculate the percentage share of each candidate into another column called **SHARE** based on the SUM of results from individual constituencies. Below is a query without the share column. See Linked Image

```
SELECT CANDIDATE_NAME, CONSTITUENCY, PARTY, RESULT
FROM parlia
WHERE REGION = 'ASHANTI'
```

[query results- Linked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2hp.png)

I did this with the ROUND function but the %Percentage share I get is using sum of all values in RESULTS column for the calculation. My target is to get the SHARE for each PARTY based on the SUM(RESULTS) of each constituency.

```
SELECT CANDIDATE_NAME, CONSTITUENCY, PARTY, RESULT,
ROUND((RESULT/(SELECT SUM(RESULT) FROM parlia)) * 100,2) AS `SHARE`
FROM parlia
WHERE REGION = 'ASHANTI'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using analytic functions here:

```sql
SELECT *, ROUND(100.0 * RESULT / SUM(RESULT) OVER (PARTITION BY CONSTITUENCY), 2) AS SHARE_PER_CONSTITUENCY
FROM e_parlia_election;
```

The window function call to `SUM` above finds the total results for each constituency.  We then normalize each record's results using this total, and convert to a two decimal percentage.

Comment: This worked perfectly. how do I order by highest percentage for each constituency.
I tried
ORDER BY SHARE_PER_CONSTITUENCY DESC; 
did not work.

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY SHARE_PER_CONSTITUENCY DESC` to my query above should work.